# Refactoring controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

As I'm sure you can tell by the following code, I'm a newbie.  But I have managed to get this to work correctly...

However, I'd really like to know how to refactor this code, as I'm sure its not the best way to do it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much in advance...

```
current_controller = params[:controller]

if current_controller == "menus" && params[:id].present?
    @menu = Menu.find(params[:id])
elsif current_controller == "menus" && params[:id].nil?
    @menu = Menu.first
elsif current_controller == "items" || current_controller == "categories"
    @menu = Menu.find(params[:menu_id])
else
    @menu = Menu.last           
end
```

Comment: You don't need to use `params[:controller]` there are already methods/helpers to get that information, you can use `controller.controller_name` anywhere to get the current controller `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my refactoring to your code:

```
@menu = case controller.controller_name
        when "menus"
            if params[:id]
                Menu.find(params[:id])
            else
                Menu.first
            end
        when "items" || "categories"
            Menu.find(params[:menu_id])
        else
            Menu.last
        end
```

Comment: Thanks Mr_Nizzle...  I tossed around using the switch.  At least I wasn't that far off of the improved code.  Dave.  If you +1, then good enough for me.  Thanks again guys..!

Comment: For anyone using Apotomo.  You can't use the controller.controller_name because the widget inherits Apotomo::Widget.  But you can use params[:controller].  Just wanted to pass it on incase anyone else was trying.

Answer (score 2):

A naive translation into (slightly) smaller code:

```
current_controller = params[:controller]
@menu = if current_controller == "menus"
          params[:id].present? Menu.find(params[:id]) : Menu.first
        elsif current_controller == "items" || current_controller == "categories"
          Menu.find(params[:menu_id])
        else
          Menu.last           
        end
```

Where does this code live?

Would it make more sense to have this in a base app controller, or filter, etc. and override in the three controllers that are special-cased? Or is this wrapped up in a helper, or...?

*Edit* Using Procs.

```
# Default if hash entry not found.
menus = Hash.new(Proc.new { |p| Menu.last })

# Items and categories controllers
itemcats = Proc.new { |p| Menu.find(p[:menu_id]) }
menus["items"] = menus["categories"] = itemcats

# Menus controller
menus["menus"] = Proc.new { |p| p[:id] ? Menu.find(p[:id]) : Menu.first }

@menu = menus[params[:controller]].call(params)
```

(More or less.)

Comment: nice i didn't know you could set a variable in such a way. What is this called?

Comment: @stephenmurdoch I'm not a big fan of it myself, might use a switch. I think it's just called "setting a variable", it just happens that the `if` statement returns the last evaled statement. There's gotta be a more-Rubyer way, though. You could have a map of lambdas and just call it based on the key.

Comment: This is very cool.  Thanks so much Dave...  I'm going to study the Proc method.

Comment: Also, I'm using it in a widget with Apotomo.  Which is effectively in an application controller without using the application controller :)  Thanks again..!

Comment: @Adam I'd hold off and see if someone comes up w/ better stuff--plus I'm not sure the `Proc` thing is that great of an idea, although it has potential. Plus there was a bug in it. I'll put up a simpler gist that you can run standalone to get an idea of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but you could try using the case statement as davenewton said

```
# Case on an expression:
@menus = case params[:controller]
when "menus" && params[:id].present? then Menu.find(params[:id])
when "menus" && params[:id].nil? then Menu.first
when "items", "categories" then Menu.find(params[:menu_id])
else Menu.last           
end
```

You can replace the "then's" with semicolons if you prefer

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this Stephen...  I really appreciate it.